# css grid area is not working properly

Tags: css

Trying to use css grid template area for the first time and it"s not working at all. It puts nothing in the first row, then tries to jam everything in the second row on top of each other. I appreciate any help. Thank you. I'm using chrome 62.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Signature Urgent Care</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid">
<header>
  <img src="signatureLogo.png">
  <img src="arrow-header.png">
  <div class="address-hours">
    <p>120 2nd Street South<br>St. Petersburg, FL 33701</p>
    <p>Mon-Fri 8 AM-8 PM<br>Sat-Sun 9 AM-4 PM</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Call</p>
    <p>1.727.851.9993</p>
    <p><a href="#">Click Here for Directions</a></p>
  </div>
</header>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About Us</a></li>
    <li><a>Services</a></li>
    <li><a>Insurance / Forms</a></li>
    <li><a>Location &amp Hours</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="home-image">
  <img src="http://signatureurgentcare.com/wp-content/themes/signatureurgentcare/images/slider/13.png">
  <img src="http://signatureurgentcare.com/wp-content/themes/signatureurgentcare/images/slider/11.png">
  <img src="http://signatureurgentcare.com/wp-content/themes/signatureurgentcare/images/slider/12.png">
  <img src="http://signatureurgentcare.com/wp-content/themes/signatureurgentcare/images/slider/7.png">
  <img src="http://signatureurgentcare.com/wp-content/themes/signatureurgentcare/images/slider/6.png">
</div>

<div class="explain">
  <img src="arrow-body.png">
  <p>Signature Urgent Care clinic is your best option if you are looking for urgent care centers or clinics in downtown Saint Petersburg, FL 33701, 33704 or 33705 area. 
  Signature Urgent Care is a walk-in medical clinic (health clinic) in downtown Stpete where no appointments are needed and you can be seen by a doctor fast.
  Signature Urgent Care is open seven days a week including weekends, after hours and holidays.</p>
  <p>Most insurances are accepted. No insurance, No problem! We offer $75 doctor's visit and best cash prices.
  Signature Urgent Care offers DOT physicals, Labs, IV fluids, Xrays, TB skin testing, drug screens and Workman's Comp services also. We treat accident
  and injury patients including motor vehicle accident patients. Call us today or just walk in and experience the difference convenience and quality makes!</p>
</div>

<section class="picture-summary">
  <a href="#"><div class="about-pic">
    <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
    <img src="aboutBTN.png">
    <ul>
      <li>Meet the doctor</li>
      <li>Tour our clinic</li>
      <li>Join our team</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>LEARN MORE</h3>
  </div></a>

  <a href="#"><div class="patient-services-pic">
    <h2>PATIENT SERVICES</h2>
    <img src="patientBTN.png">
    <ul>
      <li>Cough/cold/strep/flu</li>
      <li>Aches and Pains</li>
      <li>Physicals and vaccinations</li>
      <li>Xray, EKGs, Labs and more</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>LEARN MORE</h3>
  </div></a>

  <a href="#"><div class="insurance-pic">
    <h2>INSURANCE/FORMS</h2>
    <img src="insuranceBTN.png">
    <ul>
      <li>Insurances accepted</li>
      <li>Patient forms</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>LEARN MORE</h3>
  </div>
  </a>

</section>

<footer>
<div class="hours">
  <h2>Our Hours</h2>
  <p>Mon-Fri 8 AM-8 PM<br>Sat-Sun 9 AM-4 PM</p>
  <p>Phone: 727-851-9993<br>Fax: 727-851-9992</p>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SignatureUC/?ref=page_internal"><img src="facebook.png"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/SignatureUC"><img src="twitter.png"></a>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/106387525484792113281"><img src="google.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="Address">
  <h2>Address</h2>
  <p>120 2nd Street South<br>St. Petersburg, FL 33701</p>
  <p>We provide urgent care services on a walk-in basis to: St. Petersburg, 
  Old Northeast, Kenwood, Gulfport, St.Pete Beach, Lealman, Pinellas Park, 
  Harbor Bluffs, Belleair Bluffs, Treasure Island,
  Madeira Beach, North Redington Beach, Kenneth City, Bay Pines, Indian Shores, Largo.</p>
</div>
<div class="Parking">
  <h2>Parking</h2>
  <p>Parking is validated. Parking is conveniently located right across the street at
  the Rowdies’ Garage, previously called New McNulty Garage (101 2nd St S, St Petersburg)
  or the SouthCore Parking Garage (100 1st Avenue South). Park and bring the ticket with you.
  Signature Urgent Care will give you a voucher for parking if you are seen in 
  the clinic. Street parking is available right in front of the clinic.</p>
</div>

</footer>
<section class="copy">
  <p>&copy 2015 Signature Urgent Care. All Rights Reserved</p>
</section>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the css. Stack won't let me post this because it says it is mostly code, but not sure what else to say.

```
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
grid-template-areas:
"header header header header header"
"nav nav nav nav nav nav"
"home home home home home"
"ex ex ex ex ex ex"
"sum sum sum sum sum"
"foot foot foot foot foot"
"copy copy copy copy copy";

 }

header {
 grid-area: header; 
}

nav {
grid-area: nav; 
}

.home-image {
grid-area: home;
} 

.explain {
grid-area: ex;
}

.picture-summary {
grid-area: sum;
}

footer {
grid-area: foot;
}

.copy {
grid-area: copy;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and possible a demo of your code as a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), CodePen, or a snippet.

Comment: Seeing the html would help as well. Also, what browser are you using? Some browsers do not support the grid template area feature yet.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the grid area cells in each row match up with the column declarations. Five columns have been declared, but in the cases of the nav row and ex row, there are currently six cells in each. The cells need to form a rectangle, like as follows:

```
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header"
    "nav nav nav nav nav"
    "home home home home home"
    "ex ex ex ex ex"
    "sum sum sum sum sum"
    "foot foot foot foot foot"
    "copy copy copy copy copy";
```